# Getting Google Maps-esque tableview drawer to continue scrolling with velocity once the drawer is open

Tags: ios, google-maps, scroll, tableview, drawer

I have a bottom drawer (made up of just a tableview) laying on top of a mapview. I'm currently using gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: to work with the pan gestures for both the dragging of the drawer and the scrolling of the tableview. The issue is, when I drag to open the drawer from its partially-open state, I'd like the velocity of the drag to convert to tableview-scrolling-velocity once the drawer has reached the top of the view (and is in its fully open state). Both Google Maps and Yelp do this, and it looks/feels very natural, but I'm completely stumped as to how they're making it work.

[image]